# How to do a foreach for an array with values that have to match specific key and the same value from another array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two arrays with data from my database:

Cases array and photo's array from api:

```js
{
  "cases": [{
    "id": 3,
    "photo_id": 14
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "photo_id": 0
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "photo_id": 13
  }],
  "photos": [{
    "id": 6,
    "file": "\/images\/1556196076cache_f50f03558d201b8eb2a9af90f0838cee.png"
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "file": "\/images\/1556198414cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "file": "\/images\/1556198946cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "file": "\/images\/1556726055dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": 14,
    "file": "\/images\/1556791722dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
  }]
}
```

Now if any photo_id from the cases array matches any id from the photos array with the same value, i have to extract the file key from that specific index with the matching id. And push them as a new key value pair to the cases array at the correct index.

What i now have is the following:

```
    this.state = {
        cases: [],
        photos: [],
    };

getCases() {
    axios
        .get('/cases/api')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({
                cases: response.data.cases,
                photos: response.data.photos,
            });
            console.log(this.state.cases);
        })
}

addPhotos() {
    var photoIds = this.state.photos.map(function (player) {
        return player.id;
    });

    var casesIds = this.state.cases.map(function (player) {
        return player.photo_id;
    });

    casesIds = casesIds.filter(function (item) {
        return photoIds.includes(item);
    });

    console.log(casesIds);


}
```

The output of this are the values that exists in the cases array from the photos array.

so [13, 14].

what should i do next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Iterate over `cases` and do [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) against `photos`. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) like this:

```
const newCases = this.state.cases.map(({ photo_id, ...rest }) => {
  const obj = { ...rest };
  this.state.photos.find(ph => {
    if(ph.id === photo_id) {
      obj.file = ph.file;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return obj;
});
```

**Live example:**

```js
const data = {
  "cases": [{
    "id": 3,
    "photo_id": 14
  }, {
    "id": 2,
    "photo_id": 0
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "photo_id": 13
  }],
  "photos": [{
    "id": 6,
    "file": "\/images\/1556196076cache_f50f03558d201b8eb2a9af90f0838cee.png"
  }, {
    "id": 11,
    "file": "\/images\/1556198414cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
  }, {
    "id": 12,
    "file": "\/images\/1556198946cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
  }, {
    "id": 13,
    "file": "\/images\/1556726055dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
  }, {
    "id": 14,
    "file": "\/images\/1556791722dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
  }]
};

const newCases = data.cases.map(({ photo_id, ...rest }) => {
  const obj = { ...rest };
  data.photos.find(ph => {
    if(ph.id === photo_id) {
      obj.file = ph.file;
      return true;
    }
  });
  return obj;
});

console.log(newCases);
```

Comment: How is this solution any different from the one I've already posted in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Normalise your data. Convert your `photos` array to an object with `photo_id` as keys, for easy access.

You could do something like the following:

```
addPhotos() {
    var photosMap = this.state.photos.reduce(function (acc, each) {
      acc[each.id] = each; // or you could just save the corresponding filename
      return acc;
    }, {});

    var photoFiles = this.state.cases.reduce(function (acc, each) { // you could alternatively use Array.filter too.
      if (photosMap[each.photo_id]) {
        acc.push(photosMap[each.photo_id]);
      }
      return acc;
    }, []);

    console.log(photoFiles);

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the objects as below snippet and use it to render your view.

```js
const obj = {
    "cases": [{
        "id": 3,
        "photo_id": 14
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "photo_id": 0
    }, {
        "id": 1,
        "photo_id": 13
    }],
    "photos": [{
        "id": 6,
        "file": "\/images\/1556196076cache_f50f03558d201b8eb2a9af90f0838cee.png"
    }, {
        "id": 11,
        "file": "\/images\/1556198414cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
    }, {
        "id": 12,
        "file": "\/images\/1556198946cache_702c216fa5a4d75d74db237ddf97b012.png"
    }, {
        "id": 13,
        "file": "\/images\/1556726055dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
    }, {
        "id": 14,
        "file": "\/images\/1556791722dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"
    }]
};

const photoIds = obj.cases.reduce((acc, val) => {
    acc[val.photo_id] = val;
    return acc;
}, {});

const res = obj.photos.filter(val => photoIds[val.id]);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function addPhotos(cases, photos){
    return cases.map(function (currentCase) {
            const foundPhoto = photos.find(function(currentPhoto){
                return currentPhoto.id === currentCase.photo_id;
            });
            currentCase.photo_path = foundPhoto? foundPhoto.file : "/images/blank_image.jpg";
            return currentCase;
    });
};

console.log(addPhotos(this.state.cases, this.state.photos));
//Output: [{"id":3,"photo_id":14,"photo_path":"/images/1556791722dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"},{"id":2,"photo_id":0,"photo_path":"images/blank_image.jpg"},{"id":1,"photo_id":13,"photo_path":"/images/1556726055dewekkpot.nl_short.jpg"}]
```